# Logo resizing issues on Tablet and Mobile

Tags: css, prestashop

On my site, the logo is up to search block when I try to view the site from tablets and phones, but from a PC it is OK. I included a photo to show you what I mean. Can anyone help me fix this?

As look from tablets and phones:

[image: As look from tablets and phones]

Comment: Include your HTML, CSS and JS/JQuery applicable to the issues you wish to resolve.

Comment: Please add the default logo of your theme and show us where the logo is supposed to be on mobile

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your image width and height are predefined. This means that no matter what device you're on, the image will keep to the defined width/height.

You will need to make your image responsive.

You can do this by wrapping the image in a `div` that's got a defined width/height (perhaps a bootstrap grid column) and then apply Bootstrap's `.img-responsive' class on your image.

I'd provide a code example once you post your code & the position of where the image needs to be. (see comments on your main thread)

Comment: Ok thank you i change the search module with another and it work

Answer (score 0):

Try add .img-responsive class to the  tag in your theme files.